# In android How to track the other people using GPS?

Tags: android

I want to track my friend using GPS when he is 1 or 2 km far from me. Is there any help or **link** to solve this problem I goggled it allot but can't be able to find more appropriate information about this please tell me how can i do this or what is the best approach (api) to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Do we need a `creepy-stalker` tag now?

Answer (score 0):

Without that persons or network provider permission you cant access there gps location. Its only solution that your friend and you both using a any android application which has a GPS feature an sharing a location. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for response, yes me and my friend open the gps of our devices but i want to develop these kind of application, if u have any suppot or link please let me know thanks...

Comment: you can do it in many ways, In application whenever your friend's device has a GPS enable then from that device's your app just send data (location) to you by a sms,e-mail or post data on server then from there you will access it. Thanks.